# C++ wrapper for bound member function on resource constrained MCU

Tags: c++, embedded, function-pointers, microprocessors

I am trying to implement a pointer to member function wrapper where the return type and parameter types are known but the class type of the member function is not known. This is for a C++ project targeting resource constrained (No heap allocation/c++ standard library) microprocessor.

The following code seems to work (you can run it [HERE](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:57,endLineNumber:34,positionColumn:57,positionLineNumber:34,selectionStartColumn:57,selectionStartLineNumber:34,startColumn:57,startLineNumber:34),source:%27//can!%27t+use+any+c%2B%2B+std+libs+or+heap+allocation%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+Ret,typename...+Args%3E%0Astruct+member_cb%0A%7B%0A++++template%3Ctypename+T%3E%0A++++void+set_cb(T+*obj_,Ret+(T::*func)(Args...))%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++obj+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cmember_cb*%3E(obj_)%3B%0A++++++++cb+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3CRet+(member_cb::*)(Args...)%3E(func)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++Ret+operator()(Args...+num)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+(obj-%3E*cb)(num...)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++member_cb*+obj%3B%0A++++Ret+(member_cb::*cb)(Args...)%3B%0A%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Bar%7B%0A%0A++++void+someFunc(int+n2)%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22someFunc+called+with+parameter:+%25d%5Cn%22,n2)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B+%0A++++//class+type+of+Bar+is+not+known+at+wrapper+creation%0A++++member_cb%3Cvoid,int%3E+foo%3B%0A++++%0A++++Bar+bar%3B%0A++++%0A++++foo.set_cb(%26bar,+%26Bar::someFunc)%3B%0A++++%0A++++foo(42)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:%27713%27)),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)) and it fulfills our general requirements, but it uses reinterpret_cast hackery.

```
//can't use any c++ std libs or heap allocation
#include <cstdio>

template<typename Ret,typename... Args>
struct member_cb
{

    template<typename T>
    void set_cb(T *obj_,Ret (T::*func)(Args...))
    {
        obj = reinterpret_cast<member_cb*>(obj_);
        cb = reinterpret_cast<Ret (member_cb::*)(Args...)>(func);
    }

    Ret operator()(Args... num)
    {
        return (obj->*cb)(num...);
    }

    member_cb* obj;
    Ret (member_cb::*cb)(Args...);

};

struct Bar{

    void someFunc(int n2){
        printf("someFunc called with parameter: %d\n",n2);
    }

};

int main()
{ 
    //class type of Bar is not known at wrapper creation
    member_cb<void,int> foo;
    
    Bar bar;
    
    foo.set_cb(&bar, &Bar::someFunc);
    
    foo(42);
}
```

I want to do this without the reinterpret_cast. I believe there is a solution using a lambda that is created by the set_cb() function something like this:

```
template<typename Ret,typename... Args>
struct member_cb
{
    template<typename T>
    void set_cb(T *obj_,Ret (T::*func)(Args...))
    {
        cb_func = [=](Args...num)
        {
            (obj_->*func)(num...);
        };
    }

    Ret operator()(Args... args)
    {
        return cb_func(args...);
    }

    Ret (*cb_func)(Args...);
}
```

The above code will not compile (you can try it [HERE](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwA7KSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEAdIADqgKhE4MHt6%2BAcGp6Y4C4ZExLPGJ/tJ2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn5Btpj2RQwNTQQl0XEJSbaNza25HQrjAxFD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwcAPQ7ogxgHAQA1F5KJ4YAniemltYnM%2BgntHixCickJwiYTMmXtFoqFEPRMGgAguZ/BFkN4sCcTP43Mgnk5EdgwZCIQRMCxkgYcYi3AQrslGKxMCcAEqYAikElk5hsAB0rJO4OIwAU6MxM2IXgcJzYi2IAH1kLFMSZAlYISd5SccXiCZgiQzyWwTgAVHlyhUAN1QeGeSgI4tiEC1JwAVKhYtpRaQaadLSAQNaqF4GMhlhAOVzWczlstMQqETLQ2GFRLRZ7vQj/AARBEAVisSZMKcTfs5CkDDB8Ib1UfDsvBJZLEDtDoAtOiPV6fRACyxAyH/GWK%2BHE4jOwrpT2IZH5c7PmTiEwiMQIL7/Xm2U0uUXy/2I8Wo8RaRsGLdYrHGxBF/Og73h92pevRxBrTG402523T0PAj2OxfwXyBacLE1pWWz4axqPKgbAAGIHhEpwMGYIZriuJbJMQkFUBA5hmAoIGYOB8aiICmDPAA7oQCAnMkTQUjiiQImYKboJmbgMGhpDQe2fbygO74cW%2BQ4QpBQpMBEM5SjKCLrnssJMAoHzqp8VAnD%2BxAnHgHwMKgpwANaqQRO6TicBETsk463Juk6ZGewoVOaRKAeg5CCOiJz8KgT7waJrkKScsS/txrlnk5zKmuaqFmAAbF5ZDUSFCluhhYGNqxZ5%2BagqAQJIMEuQOHCrLQnAprwfgcFopCoJwbjWA8GEbFs1H%2BDw9KaFlqzqSAKYaPonCSPlDXFZwvAKCAbUEA1qxwLAMCICA6wEMkXh0hQEBoHidAjFwIT4FOej8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOohW8PpfycDw2W5V1p09RwADys0zacqByaoAAcIU1iFkgnMAyDICcXBcMyZgnBAHhLfQilQlwyy8ENp3BqQzWte1HCdaQLAtW1BVFSVHB9QN9XI6Qo0TYtyTLWQ81UzTIDACDZh8HQlH9RAsTdbEERNFcl28ItbCCA9DC0Pzd1YCwhjAOIkt4JudT6pg/V3Zgqi1LN2xFZBXTda8sQTsQVweFg3UEEhOPcFlfAGFyABqeCYARD2MgLB3CLhe3SFt8hKGo3W6KtBhGCg5WWPobz9bATLsFQLB0sriQcIEXD%2BI1xXJD0qs1k8iKJncViWFIfVdLUPQuAw7ieG0ehhPMZQVHoBQZAIkx%2BKtLc9IMjcrZ03T1LM7d6DUdQCH0zQ98MiSrTM/TD7PsxTyKEirJVmx7fSm7bFdGN5cx3WE5932/f9gPA6D4OQ%2BHNgnLghBfHDpAnFD1MwzV8OI8Nqw/EwWCJDODGWMcbo3xrwQmxNBrf1RrjDG6cD53QgaTLQKMcocDMLdAmvVkEZyTukZwkggA%3D)). Problem is that the regular function pointers like cb_func can only point to lambdas that have no captures, and the lambda has to capture the obj_ and the func parameters. Any suggestions on making this work would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a problem: in C++, pointer-to-member types aren’t guaranteed to all have the same size. And they indeed differ, at least when multiple inheritance is involved. That means, *any* solution will have its drawbacks, which can be: compiler dependence, heap allocation, bloated `member_cb`, bloated text segment (tons of trampolines), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, compiler-independent solution:

```cpp
template <typename Signature>
struct member_cb;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct member_cb<Ret(Args...)>
{
    template <typename T, Ret (T::*func)(Args...)>
    static Ret wrapper(void *object, Args&&... args) {
        T *o = reinterpret_cast<T *>(object);
        return (o->*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    
    template <typename T, Ret (T::*func)(Args...)>
    void set_cb(T *obj_)
    {
        obj = obj_;
        cb_func = wrapper<T, func>;
    }

    // since C++17:
    template <auto func, typename T>
    void set_cb(T *obj_)
    {
        obj = obj_;
        cb_func = wrapper<T, func>;
    }

    Ret operator() (Args&& ...args)
    {
        return cb_func(obj, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void *obj;
    Ret (*cb_func)(void *, Args&&...);
};

...
member_cb<void(int)> foo;
foo.set_cb<Bar, &Bar::someFunc>(&bar);
foo.set_cb<&Bar::someFunc>(&bar); // since C++17
```

The key limitation is that `someFunc` must be known at compile-time at the place `set_cb` is called, so you can’t take arbitrary method pointer and convert it to a `member_cb`. It is possible to change the object keeping the method pointer intact, though (but that’s not type-safe).

Another possible problem is that the compiler may need to emit a `wrapper` instance for each and every method that is ever used as a callback.

The upside is that it should work on any C++11-compliant compiler (C++17 for nicer syntax), and `member_cb` itself is small.

Comment: This is a solid answer, but it looks like either the `cb_func` needs to have the `Args` be rvaule reference, or `wrapper` needs to not be an rvalue reference(compiler explorer link [HERE](https://godbolt.org/z/Te9TYzofG))

Comment: Fixed that, thanks. Note that despite using the same syntax, that is not an rvalue reference: due to `Args` being a template argument, it is an universal reference that can become any type of reference depending on what `Args` are, like in https://godbolt.org/z/nxa18snzY . Not very useful here though as `Args` are fixed and not deduced.